# How can I customize messages.phtml in vendor directory in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I copied

```
\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\messages.phtml
```

to

```
\app\code\[my_project]\Theme\view\frontend\templates\messages.phtml
```

and cleared cache by this command:

```
docker-compose run --rm cli bin/magento cache:flush
docker-compose run --rm cli bin/magento index:reindex
```

But after that, the messages.phtml in the vendor is still loaded.

To confirm the messages.phtml in the vendor is really used, I want to directly modify

```
\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\messages.phtml
```

but it can not be updated because my editor shows it is forbidden to write.

So, I'm not sure the messages.phtml in the vendor is really loaded.

How can I override or overwrite messages.phtml in a vendor?

The version of Magento is probably 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the file

```
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml
```

you have to copy it into

```
/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/messages.phtml
```

Do your modifications in that file and clear the cache. If changes are still not applied though, try clearing the `var/view_preprocessed` folder: `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*`.

Comment: thank you very much! your answer solved my problem.